# simple average returns "incorrect" or not, value

Tags: python, python-2.7

python 2.7:

```
def median(lista):
    lista.sort()
    print(lista)
    x = len(lista)
    if x == 1:
        return lista[0]
    elif len(lista) % 2 != 0:
        return lista[((x-1)/2)]
    else:
        y = lista[(x / 2) - 1]
        z = lista[(x / 2)]
        print (y,z)
        return (y + z) / 2

print(median([1,6,3,4,2,5]))
```

displays:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
(3, 4)
3
None
```

why not 3.5?

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do return sum / 2.0 instead of sum / 2

By default the answer would be an int unless explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Nick M provides you the solution, but I'd like to add some explanation.

In Python there are different variable types for numbers, most important being `int` and `float`:

```
type(1)
>>> int
type(1.0)
>>> float
```

When you operate with integers (variables of type `int`) you get as result   also the type `int`:

```
5 / 2
>>> 2
```

You can mix integers and floats together, where a type coercion happens, and the integers are internally converted to floats, getting a float as result:

```
5 / 2.0
>>> 2.5
```

You can also explicitly convert the variable types using the methods `int()` or `float()`:

```
int(1.0)
>>> 1
float(1)
>>> 1.0
```

I hope this helps you for better understanding.

EDIT: official documentation for numeric types in Python 2.7:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: @rosh Thank you for the remark. The question is explicitly about Python 2.7 and everything in my answer is related only to this version.

Comment: It wasn't confrontational, you put 'in python' and I didn't read everything on the page. Don't be shirty.

Comment: Hey @rosh I know it wasn't confrontational, and I'm not shirty at all. I also thanked you for the remark. Don't be cheeky :)